# Which countries can an English app be sold in?

Tags: windows-phone-7, internationalization

For an app in English, how can I get a list of where it can be sold? I've found lot's of information about how to internationalize, how to get a list of all countries in English, etc. but not a list of English speaking countries.

This is an XNA game and I'd love to make it available to the entire world, but I can't imagine creating a separate set of pngs for every language and wouldn't even know how to do the translation... so English it is for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you have Facebook/Twitter integration or link there, you can sell it on all markets.
It, for sure, depends on the content, but there is no general restrictions

Twitter/Facebook is prohibited in China and maybe in some arabic countries

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=countries%20speaking%20english) `Wolfram` answer. It has the amount of English speakers per country.